# Mootools .destroy method doesn't work after importing elements into DOM with load

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm simply trying to import html into a new node, and strip out elements with the class '.prototype':

```
var statics = new Element('div');

statics.load('statics.html')

statics.getElements('.prototype').destroy();

statics.inject($('main'));
```

This doesn't work as expected. Elements with the class '.prototype' still exist. Any insight?

Comment: write what statics.html is returning

Comment: just to clarify, the selector `.prototype` is for class `prototype`, right? You don't actually have `class=".prototype"` in your html do you?

Answer (score 2):

If that is the code unaltered, then the problem with that excerpt is that `Request.HTML` makes an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest`.

When `.load()` gets called, it makes an `XMLHttpRequest` to `statics.html`, but before it can return with the HTML payload, execution of the script continues, and `.getElements('.prototype')` is run against `statics`, which is currently an empty `div`, so no elements are found.

To cheat, you can change the ajax request so that it is asynchronous:

```
statics.set('load', { async: false });
```

However, the proper way to do this while maintaining asynchronicity would be to use an `onSuccess` callback:

```
statics.set('load', {
    onSuccess: function() {
        var toDestroy = statics.getElements('.prototype'),
            numDestroy = toDestroy.length,
            x;

        for(x=0;x<numDestroy;x++) {
            toDestroy[x].destroy();
        }
    }
});
```